# render my block of custom field on the customer account edit page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add some custom fields using my block.
Problem is that block is not rendering inside the form tag or before the submit button(see the screenshot 1).

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is the code of rendering the block on Account edit page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <customer_account_edit>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
                    <block type="customfield/Register" name="customfield_registrationnnn" template="vss_customfield/register.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use before =" module name of magento".
You can insert your code before magento

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no hook/handle to insert new/custom fields in account edit form.

Either you can **overwrite the customer/form/edit.phtml** in your module's layout file.

1) Put below snippet in your module's layout XML.

```
<customer_account_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourModule/customer/form/edit.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

2) Copy your theme's

> customer/form/edit.phtml

to

> yourModule/customer/form/edit.phtml

3) Now in your new file, you can put your custom fields.